# React setState is not updating state in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

Why react `setState` is not updating state in class component in my code?

In the console, my data is shown (`console.log(data)`),
but `setState` is not updating state.

What's the problem?

```js
export default class Posts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            posts: null,
            isPending: true
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/all_posts/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                this.setState({ posts: data });
            })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="posts">
                {this.isPending && <div>loading...</div>}
                {this.state.posts && this.state.posts.map((post) => {
                    <div className="post" key={post.id}>
                        {post.slug}
                    </div>
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not updating the state ? Did you put any console.log for `this.state.data` (inside the render method) to check whether it's an array of objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 3 errors.

1. You are checking for `this.isPending` instead of `this.state.isPending`
2. Your map function is not returning anything. Whenever you use curly braces (`{}`) you need to add the `return` keyword. If you don't use the curly braces you should use an implicit return which is done by using parenthesis around your returned object/component. So change it to this...

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className="posts">
                {this.state.isPending && <div>loading...</div>}
                {this.state.posts && this.state.posts.map((post) => (
                    <div className="post" key={post.id}>
                        {post.slug}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

3. Finally, when you set the value of the posts after the API call in the `componentDidMount`, you should set the `isPending` to `false`. So something like this...

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/api/all_posts/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ posts: data, isPending: false });
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You put this.isPending instead of this.state.isPending